# Data Sorting in an array keeping first and last element position fixed in angular2

Tags: javascript, angular

Sort ascending and decending order in the desired format? Given below is the shdata and desired output?

```
 //data is in the given below format
       shdata = [
            { 'Name': 'A', 'Data': '57.6' },
             { 'Name': 'B', 'Data': '-10.6' },
            { 'Name': 'C', 'Data': '-50.6' },
            { 'Name': 'D', 'Data': '50.6' },
            { 'Name': 'E', 'Data': '10.6' },
            { 'Name': 'F', 'Data': '0.6' },
            { 'Name': 'G', 'Data': '-5.6' },
          ];
```

I want to convert it in sort ascending order and descending order like(Desired output).

**Note:** **shdata[0]** and **shdata[last]** should retain their position as it is, the sorting should be in between them.

```
     shdata = [
            { 'Name': 'A', 'Data': '57.6' },
             { 'Name': 'C', 'Data': '-50.6' },
            { 'Name': 'B', 'Data': '-10.6' },
            { 'Name': 'F', 'Data': '0.6' },
            { 'Name': 'E', 'Data': '10.6' },
            { 'Name': 'D', 'Data': '50.6' },   
            { 'Name': 'G', 'Data': '-5.6' },
          ];
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort Can be of help

Answer (score 4):

Here is a simple solution to this problem.

```
    shdata = [
        { 'Name': 'A', 'Data': '57.6' },
        { 'Name': 'B', 'Data': '-10.6' },
        { 'Name': 'C', 'Data': '-50.6' },
        { 'Name': 'D', 'Data': '50.6' },
        { 'Name': 'E', 'Data': '10.6' },
        { 'Name': 'F', 'Data': '0.6' },
        { 'Name': 'G', 'Data': '-5.6' },
        ];

    var first = shdata.shift();
    var last = shdata.pop();

    shdata.sort( function (a,b) {
      if( parseFloat(a.Data) > parseFloat(b.Data)){
        return 1;
      }else {
        return 0;
      }
    });

    shdata.splice(0,0,first);
    shdata.push(last);
```

Comment: Sorry, not getting sorted data.

Comment: this.shdata.sort(function (a: any, b: any) { return a.Data - b.Data; }); is working for me.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like the simplest idea would be to [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) the array into the subset that you want to sort (second to second-to-last indices would be 1 to length - 1), [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) that subset, and then recreate the array.

Since you're trying to sort objects, you'll have to define a custom sort function. Also, since it seems like your `Data` property is a `number` but stored as a string, you'll have to do the conversion in the sort function. Alternately, store numbers instead of strings. Once you have your subset, you can call the subset's `sort` like so:

```
// sort ascending
subset.sort(function(a, b) {
    return parseFloat(a.Data) - parseFloat(b.Data);
});
```

After that, it's a simple matter of putting your pieces together.

```
var result = [shdata[0]];
result = result.concat(subset);
result.push(shdata[shdata.length - 1]);
```

Comment: What is subset here. I can't get it . Please, clarify for better understanding.

Comment: In this instance, a subset is a small part of a larger array. To get the subset you want (everything except the first and last elements), use [`Array.prototype.slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice).